# Domain condition not working for a specific group

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have created 4 groups:

1- group_sprogroup_projets: can see the validation button

2-group_sprogroup_management: can see the validation button

3-group_manager: can see all records

4-group_purchase:can see all records

I have two users:

-Directeur: affected to groups 2 and 3 so the button is appearing in all records

-respACHAT: affecter to groups 1 and 4 so the button is appearing in all records

in Python file, i have a variable 'assigned_to_responsible_affected_to' which is a Many2one field.

I want to hide a button for these two users if the variable assigned_to_responsible_affected_to is different from the logged user :

'assigned_to_responsible_affected_to','!=',user
The problem is that this is perfectly working for the "respACHAT" and not working for the other user "Directeur".
Here is my code:

```
<record id="hide_validation_button" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hide validation button</field>
        <field name="model">sprogroup.purchase.request</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" 
ref="sprogroup_purchase_request.view_sprogroup_purchase_request_form"/>    
 <field name="groups_id" 
  eval="[(6, 0,  

 [ref('sprogroup_purchase_request.group_sprogroup_management'),
 ref('sprogroup_purchase_request.group_sprogroup_projets')])]"/>  
            <field name="domain"> 
  [('assigned_to_responsible_affected_to','!=',user)]</field>      
                <field name="arch" type="xml">

  <xpath expr="//header/button[@name='button_to_approve']" position="attributes">
                     <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>                       

                    </xpath>

                     </field>
     </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `assigned_to_responsible_affected_to`'s target mode might be `res.users`: in this case, as far as I remember, current user value passed by the view's evaluation context is a many2one-like variable.
Try and change the domain declaration in this way:

```html
<field name="domain">
    [('assigned_to_responsible_affected_to', '!=', user.id)]
</field>
```

Let us know if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I'v already tried this before but it didn't fix my problem. The weird thing is that it's working for one group and not working for the other!